# Samples in Microsoft CRM 2015 SDK not cooperating

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2015

I downloaded the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 SDK. I just want to work through one of the samples that it provides. However, upon opening the sample (which is located in the SDK folder) it says that I am missing a bunch of assembly references for a ton of keywords in the file. I have not modded the SDK in any way, so why would I be having these errors?

For reference, I am trying to do the "Quickstart with simplified connection" sample, thought it appears to do this with any sample that I open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared that when I had downloaded the 2015 CRM SDK that it wasn't fully released... which is why the samples were not working

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried doing the same and it seems that the issue is because of the .Net framework. The SDK uses 4.5.2 and If we use anything lower than that then we get the error you mentioned above.